# Emberjs Handlebars precompiling

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

My Emberjs app is running slowly so I wanted to precompile my template to ease the runtime a bit. However I'm lost on how to proceed. I read http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html and Emberjs introduction but no, all I could do was just creating a template file as instructed on the site, and I cannot figure out what and how to do with this template file in Emberjs.

How can I precompile templates in Emberjs? What should I do with the template file to use it in Emberjs?

Comment: If you are using `gulp` I recently published a package to npm called [gulp-ember-templates](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-ember-templates) which will compile your handlebars templates into javascript and then you can concat them into a single file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to precompile Emberjs Handlebar templates with nodejs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171583/easy-way-to-precompile-emberjs-handlebar-templates-with-nodejs)

Answer (score -16, accepted):

You can set the precompiled handlebars output to the template property (not templateName) on you ember view. This is what ember also does under the hood

```
MyApp.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: "myViewWhatever",
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<p>{{blah}}</p>'),
})
```

Comment: This is not precompilation.

Comment: this still compiles on the client

Answer (score 38):

To clarify, Thomas' example as-written is still doing the template compilation at run-time. I think his point, though, was that after you've loaded your [precompiled Ember-Handlebars templates](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/node-ember-precompile) you can do this:

```
MyApp.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  template: Ember.TEMPLATES.mytemplate,
})
```

The problem with using [Handlebars' built-in precompiler](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html) is that Ember's Handlebars implementation adds some functionality on top of what Handlebars itself provides, so you'll want to install the [ember-precompile package](https://github.com/gabrielgrant/node-ember-precompile), which provides basically the same interface as the `handlebars` command-line utility, but using Ember's Handlebars implementation.

This will avoid you having to change all your `templateName`s to `template`s and having to add in the `Ember.TEMPLATES...` in each view, since it automatically updates Ember's built-in template cache.

So, assuming you've already loaded your pre-complied `templates.js` file as output from `ember-precompile templates/*.handlebars -f templates/templates.js`, here's a more complete example snippet of a worker import/initialization order:

```
<script src="/lib/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/ember-1.0.pre.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/ember-data-latest.js"></script>
<script>
  var App = Ember.Application.create();
</script>
<script src="/templates/templates.js"></script>
<script src="/js/models.js"></script>
<script src="/js/views.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="/js/router.js"></script>
<script>
  App.initialize();
</script>
```

Comment: I think your examples are showing vanilla handlebars compilation. I was under the impression that Ember.Handlebars should be used to precompile templates.

Comment: @LukeMelia you're totally right, that wasn't very clear -- I'd called the ember-precompile script "handlebars" on my machine, which is really confusing. It's now `ember-precompile`, and installable via NPM :)

Comment: I found out the hard way that my compiled templates were using "Handlebars.helpers" instead of "Ember.Handlebar.helpers".  And so, most of the common ember helpers - view, partial, outlet, etc, weren't available, and it was driving me crazy.  Thanks!

Comment: Got excited this would work, too soon.  I'm not getting this error "Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current runtime. Please update your precompiler to a newer version (>= 1.0.0-rc.3) or downgrade your runtime to an older version (<= 1.0.rc.2)"

Comment: But then I found this, which works like a charm: https://npmjs.org/package/ember-tools#ember-generate---scaffold-resource

Answer (score 7):

You could also use Grunt.js and a handlebars template compiler. I've used the "grunt-ember-templates" plugin and it works well.

http://gruntjs.com/

https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-ember-templates

Answer (score 3):

Here is a gist showing how to precompile handlebars templates and add the result to the Ember.TEMPLATES object, which Ember consults to resolve named templates.

https://gist.github.com/2013669

Comment: How can i precompile partials?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Gulp for builds, and precompiling templates looks like this:

```
var handlebars = require('gulp-ember-handlebars');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

var SRC = {
    TEMPLATES: ['app/templates/**/*.{hbs,html}']
};

gulp.task('templates', function() {
  return gulp.src(SRC.TEMPLATES)
    .pipe(handlebars({outputType: 'browser'}))
    .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST.SCRIPTS));
});
```

Then I use the Handlebars runtime library rather than the full version.

Ember-Handlebars: https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-ember-handlebars

Answer (score 0):

You can precompile in the client's browser, as Thomas Bartelmess stated.

You can also precompile using handlebars via nodejs (taken from my very own Jakefile):

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
precompile = (function () {
    //Lovingly extracted from Ember's sources.
    var objectCreate = Object.create || function (parent) {
            function F() {}
            F.prototype = parent;
            return new F();
        },
        Compiler = function () {},
        JavaScriptCompiler = function () {};

    Compiler.prototype = objectCreate(Handlebars.Compiler.prototype);
    Compiler.prototype.compiler = Compiler;
    JavaScriptCompiler.prototype = objectCreate(Handlebars.JavaScriptCompiler.prototype);
    JavaScriptCompiler.prototype.compiler = JavaScriptCompiler;
    JavaScriptCompiler.prototype.namespace = "Ember.Handlebars";
    JavaScriptCompiler.prototype.initializeBuffer = function () {
        return "''";
    };
    JavaScriptCompiler.prototype.appendToBuffer = function (string) {
        return "data.buffer.push(" + string + ");";
    };
    Compiler.prototype.mustache = function (mustache) {
        if (mustache.params.length || mustache.hash) {
            return Handlebars.Compiler.prototype.mustache.call(this, mustache);
        } else {
            var id = new Handlebars.AST.IdNode(['_triageMustache']);
            if (!mustache.escaped) {
                mustache.hash = mustache.hash || new Handlebars.AST.HashNode([]);
                mustache.hash.pairs.push(["unescaped", new Handlebars.AST.StringNode("true")]);
            }
            mustache = new Handlebars.AST.MustacheNode([id].concat([mustache.id]), mustache.hash, !mustache.escaped);
            return Handlebars.Compiler.prototype.mustache.call(this, mustache);
        }
    };
    return function precompile(string) {
        var ast = Handlebars.parse(string);
        var options = {
            knownHelpers : {
                action : true,
                unbound : true,
                bindAttr : true,
                template : true,
                view : true,
                _triageMustache : true
            },
            data : true,
            stringParams : true
        };

        var environment = new Compiler().compile(ast, options);
        return new JavaScriptCompiler().compile(environment, options, undefined, true);
    };
}());

strPrecompiledTemplate = item.handlebarsTemplateFolders.map(function (dir) {
    console.info("\tProcessing " + dir);
    return readdirRecursiveSync(dir).map(function (file) {
        console.info("\t\t" + file);
        var content = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8');
        content = Handlebars.precompile(content);
        file = file.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '').replace(/^src\//g, '').substr(dir.length).replace(/^\/+/, '');
        // Pay attention: The wrap in Ember.Handlebars.template() is important!
        return "Ember.TEMPLATES['"+file+"'] = Ember.Handlebars.template("+content+");";
    }).join("\r\n");
}).join("\r\n");
```